# Box2d How to connect distance joint to the ground?

Tags: box2d

I have a rectangular fixed size world. I want to connect a body inside it to any place(near that body) in the world with a `b2DistanceJoint`. Do I need to create a large static body with the size of the world that can't collide with anything? Or is there a better method? Will it slow down simulation speed if I have around 300 bodies moving on the surface of this static body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do I need to create a large static body with the size of the world that can't collide with anything?**

No.

**Or is there a better method?**

In the wise words of master Yoda:

> Size matters not

In this case it means that the joint anchor points on a body need not be inside any of the fixtures of the body. They can be miles away if you want.

Make a small `b2body` somewhere well outside the gameplay area, make it a `b2_staticBody`, and make the fixture a sensor body so that any collisions that do happen to occur don't affect the simulation. Then use this body whenever you want to join something to the ground.

**Will it slow down simulation speed if I have around 300 bodies moving on the surface of this static body?**

Yes. The reason you want to make a *small* body is precisely because of what you mentioned. Any collisions with this body are meaningless, and box2d creates a contact object and stores it on the world for every contact between fixtures. It also iterates through this list every time the `step` function is called. So by keeping it small and out of the way you can conserve memory and cpu time.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted! And I have a static world border, so I don't even need an additional body, I guess.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help. :)